# An expression to express "daily routine doesn't make one an expert."

Tags: expressions

I'd like to make a point that by simply following a routine, as an operator following a SOP, doesn't make one an expert, i.e. it doesn't mean that the person fully understands the activity. An expert knows not only "how to do it" but also "why to do it this way" and "what are other alternative ways or what changes should be made if situation changes." How to put that neatly?

Comment: The distinction between types of knowledge at the heart of your question has been debated within philosophy for a long time. I'll be surprised if anyone comes with an adequate, short, expression. It touches on the differences between: 1) know-how v. know-that; 2) practical knowledge v. theoretical knowledge; 3) craft v. technique, and; 4) tacit knowledge v. propositional knowledge.  


For more on these issues see --> https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-how/

Comment: seeing a link to stanford i feel flattered :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was more or less a phrase in the 80's:

"Is the department of computer science at university or college a department of type writing or part of academia and research?"

It started to became mainstream in 80's for colleges and universities to teach computer programming to large numbers of students, but there was an actual concern that students would be just following standard operating procedures and not have the ability to gain an expertise of the theoretical nature in the way other academic subjects were capable of accomplishing.